# Sort dataframe by datetime, but start from 06:00?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have dataframe with column `Timestamp` and `Values`. `Timestamp` has datetime elements in rows. Elements in rows starts from `0:00` to `23:55`. I would like to sort whole dataframe by `Timestamp` column but I would like to have `06:00` in the first row (because data from `00:00` to `05:55` is next day data).

How to do it quick and properly? Tried code below, but it sorts from 0:00 to 23:55. Maybe add 1 day to datetimes after `23:55` (because all data in `Timestamp` column has the same date, only time differs)

```py
            df = df.sort_values(by=['Timestamp'])
```

df['Timestamp'] is `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: how does `df['Timestamp']` look like? is it just *time* or complete datetime?

Comment: Complete datetime : 

`431   1900-01-01 05:55:00
Name: Czas, Length: 144, dtype: datetime64[ns]
`

Comment: hm this looks like an automatically added date (input actually is only time). So for sorting, I guess the problem you have to solve how to add the date correctly to the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I've finally used solution below and it works

```py
mask = df['Timestamp'] <  dt.datetime.strptime('06:00','%H:%M')
df.loc[mask, 'Timestamp'] += pd.DateOffset(1)
df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')
```

Answer (score 1):

Before:

```
df
    Values  Timestamp
0   0   1900-01-01 00:00:00
1   1   1900-01-01 01:00:00
2   2   1900-01-01 02:00:00
3   3   1900-01-01 03:00:00
4   4   1900-01-01 04:00:00
5   5   1900-01-01 05:00:00
6   6   1900-01-01 06:00:00
7   7   1900-01-01 07:00:00
8   8   1900-01-01 08:00:00
9   9   1900-01-01 09:00:00
10  10  1900-01-01 10:00:00
11  11  1900-01-01 11:00:00
12  12  1900-01-01 12:00:00
13  13  1900-01-01 13:00:00
...
```

solution:

```
df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')
previous_day = df[df.Timestamp>='1900-01-01 06:00:00']
next_day = df[df.Timestamp<'1900-01-01 06:00:00']
df = pd.concat([previous_day,next_day])
df
    Values  Timestamp
6   6   1900-01-01 06:00:00
7   7   1900-01-01 07:00:00
8   8   1900-01-01 08:00:00
9   9   1900-01-01 09:00:00
10  10  1900-01-01 10:00:00
11  11  1900-01-01 11:00:00
12  12  1900-01-01 12:00:00
13  13  1900-01-01 13:00:00
14  14  1900-01-01 14:00:00
15  15  1900-01-01 15:00:00
16  16  1900-01-01 16:00:00
17  17  1900-01-01 17:00:00
18  18  1900-01-01 18:00:00
19  19  1900-01-01 19:00:00
20  20  1900-01-01 20:00:00
21  21  1900-01-01 21:00:00
22  22  1900-01-01 22:00:00
23  23  1900-01-01 23:00:00
0   0   1900-01-01 00:00:00
1   1   1900-01-01 01:00:00
2   2   1900-01-01 02:00:00
3   3   1900-01-01 03:00:00
4   4   1900-01-01 04:00:00
5   5   1900-01-01 05:00:00
```

This is a solution based on your specific problem. For further processing, it may be worth changing Timestamp to full DateTime. Hope I helped :)

Comment: assuming the OPs input 'Timestamp' is actually just time strings like `"03:00:00"`, treating the root of the problem might be more efficient - e.g. parse the 'Timestamp' column to timedelta type and add it to a pre-defined start date. Sorting should then give the expected output automatically.

Comment: As he mentioned in comment: "Complete datetime : 431   1900-01-01 05:55:00 Name: Czas, Length: 144, dtype: datetime64[ns]" we are dealing with DateTime. The date was probably added automatically while reading CSV. What I would recommend solving the problem is to add a proper date. My solution is a workaround that can be proposed with rather small details provided by OP.

Comment: This is more generic solution.

Comment: *"The date was probably added automatically while reading CSV"* - I think so too, and I think that import process can easily be modified to "do the right thing".

Comment: Unfortunately, my raw data doesn't have `date` information. Only hours and minutes.

Comment: @s.paszko see my first comment - you can easily work around that by adding the time as a timedelta to a pre-defined date.